# get value of any id in form click on another class php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want a value for id `iin_no` click on client_name class in while loop, assume that there are 50 rows. on jQuery.

```
<td>
  <a href="#">
    <strong class="text-custom client_name">
      <u><?php echo $fetch_data['Name_as_per_pan']; ?></u>                                      
    </strong>
    </p>
  </a>
</td>

<div id="iin_no"> 
  <p><?php echo $fetch_data['iin']; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: what `id`? no such ID can be seen in OP

Comment: Could we have a more complete sample of your code. There seems to be some issues here - you have an extra `</p>` in the `a`, and are missing one in the `div`. The `div` itself seems to be a child of the `tr` which is invalid.

Comment: id attribute should be unique for each element .

Comment: Please post your complete code so that we can understand your problem.Current code is not helpful to understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".client_name").click( ()=> {
    $("#iin_no").html($(this).find("u").html());
});
```

Comment: thank you so much Nir for answer, but value is return in [object.object] form . so could u please help me. how can i store in variable.

Comment: Are you trying to output the result to an alert? try logging it to the console.

Comment: on the console answer look like this. Object[div#iin_no]

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$(".client_name ul").on('click',function () {
       $("#iin_no").html($(this).html());
});
```

**Modified:-**

```
$(".client_name ul").on('click',function () {
           var id = $("#iin_no p").eq(0).html();
           alert(id);
    });
```

I thing it will help you.

Comment: thank you so much Bibhudatta for answer, but value is return in [object.object] form . so can u please help me. how can i store in variable.

Comment: Okay for storing in variable you can do like this `var clientName=$(this).html();` and then  alert the value like `alert(clientName.toSource());` and check the data is coming or not ?

Comment: i want value for ID ='iin_no' ..but according to ur code it is return to me  id=client_name"  value.

Comment: can you please explain  me what you want to do ?
I understand  from our question that  you have multiple row of `<u><?php echo $fetch_data['Name_as_per_pan']; ?></u> ` and when user click on it you need its value in `iin_no` div .Is it you want or anything else ?

Comment: no, when user click on <u><?php echo $fetch_data['Name_as_per_pan']; ?></u> link ..then we want value of iin_no.

Comment: Then use the modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly working. Please change only id of `iin_no` to class.

```
$('strong.client_name').on('click',function(){
    var iin_no = $(this).parents('tr').find('div.iin_no').text();
});
```